# Exporting features when column value between specific percentiles

Tags: qgis, export, select-by-attribute, statistics

I want to do a statistical analysis. I need to export some features. Their column value between 10%-90% (or 20%-80%) percentile in order to avoid outliers' effect. I can't find a function in the expression window. There are q1, q3, median. They return 25%, 75% and 50% percentile values

There are related posts I found here. None of them meets my need.

- [Summarizing column in QGIS field calculator?](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/143544/summarizing-column-in-qgis-field-calculator) (QGIS, Field Calculator)
- [Selecting features by quartiles in QGIS](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/383941/selecting-features-by-quartiles-in-qgis) (QGIS, Field Calculator, q1 q3)
- [Identify polygons greater than n-th percentile and perform further analyses using arcpy](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/159146/identify-polygons-greater-than-n-th-percentile-and-perform-further-analyses-usin) (ArcGIS, ArcPy)
- [Calculating Nth percentile from table in ModelBuilder of ArcMap](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/357790/calculating-nth-percentile-from-table-in-modelbuilder-of-arcmap) (ArcGIS, Model Builder, no answer)

How can I export features, their column value is between specific range like 10%-90%, 20%-80% etc?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can create a new function which returns a percentile value, then, compare the field value.

1. Open *`Select Feature by Expression`* tool
2. Create new function in the Function Editor using the script below. ([How to use the Function Editor](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#function-editor))

```py
from qgis.core import *
from qgis.gui import *
import numpy as np

values, layer = None, None
@qgsfunction(args='auto', group='Custom')
def percentile(per, layer_name, field_name, feature, parent):
    global layer, values
   
    if values is None:
        layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName(layer_name)[0]
        values = [f[field_name] for f in layer.getFeatures()]
    
    return float(np.percentile(values, per))
```

3. Run this expression to select features whose field value is between 10%-90% percentile. You can change `10` and `90` to change the range.

```py
percentile(10, @layer_name, 'FIELD') < FIELD < percentile(90, @layer_name, 'FIELD')
```

- Note: The 3rd parameter (field name) in `percentile` function must be string -> `'FIELD'`. Please read this: [Writing an expression](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_vector/expression.html#writing-an-expression)

4. Use *`Extract selected feature`* tool.

Answer (score 9):

You can use `Select by expression` and paste this expressions (see also screenshots below):

1. For the lowest 10%:

```
"value" <=
array_get(
    array_sort ( 
        array_agg ("value")
    ),
    aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'count', 
        "value"
    ) / 10 - 1
)
```

2. For the highest 10%:

```
"value" >=
array_get(
    array_sort ( 
        array_agg ("value")
    ),
    aggregate (
        @layer, 
        'count', 
        "value"
    ) / 10*9 
)
```

Combine both expressions with `or` to the the lowest 10% plus the highest 10% (0-10%, 90-100%).

Screenshot: applying this to a layer with 100 points and an attribute field called `value` containing random values from 1 to 1000, it will select the lowest 10 (from 100) `values` entries:

[image]

And for the highest values:

[image]

And combined:

[image]